# Converting a SQL query to an ARRAY in PostgreSQL with jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

Let's say I have a query of the type:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE access_codes @>
    ARRAY[(SELECT access_code FROM provisional_access)];
```

How would I write this in jooq? The best I have done so far is:

```
ctx.selectFrom(Tables.USERS).where(Tables.USERS.ACCESS_CODES).contains(
    ?? ctx.select(Tables.PROVISIONAL_ACCESS.ACCESS_CODE).from(Tables.PROVISIONAL_ACCESS) ??
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently isn't supported by jOOQ out of the box, but you can very easily implement a utility function using ["plain SQL"](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/):

```java
public static <T> Condition arrayContains(
    Field<T[]> left, Select<? extends Record1<T>> right
) {
    return DSL.condition("{0} @> ARRAY[({1})]", left, right);
}
```